# Can you explain the composition of this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, compounds

[Source](http://blogs.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/mrsfunnybones/kohinoor-and-other-british-gems/)

> We eat a few more raspberry scones and switch over to discussing the great poet Rumi and Shams of Tabriz and **when I say that back home, we often refer to him as Shams Tabrizi, she retorts, ‘You Indians are obsessed with the British, want to rhyme everything with Angrezi — affected lot!’**

What is 'that'?

Should the sentence be separated as

*When I say that back home*,

1 *we often refer to him as Shams Tabrizi* as well as
2 *she retorts, ‘You Indians are obsessed with the British, want to rhyme everything with Angrezi — affected lot!’*

The bold part is confusing me a lot.In the end, that *affected a lot* seems weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the word [that](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/that) to indicate that we are quoting somebody, so

> when I say that back home, we often refer to him as Shams Tabrizi

it is equivalent to

> When I say "Back home, we often refer to him as Shams Tabrizi"

In this context, [affected](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/affected) means **artificial and not sincere**, and [lot](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lot) means a group of people. I must admit that the woman's response does not seem to be a well considered responsed to the speaker's comment.